# Ipad App using adobe air hangs completely on trying to load an image in release build

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am trying load a png image from a url for an AIR app that is tobe deployed in Ipad. I am using air 3.6 Below is a simplified version of my code:-

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, onIconLoaded);

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, function(event:ErrorEvent):void {
 trace('security sandbox error ignored');
});

var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
trace("going for image load");
loader.load ( new URLRequest("some url"), context );

private function onIconLoaded(event:flash.events.Event):void 
{           
    trace("image loaded");
    var info:LoaderInfo = event.target as LoaderInfo;       
    addChild(info.content);

}
```

This works perfectly fine inside adobe flex builder (tried with 4.6 & 4.7). It also works fine in ipad when done fast packaging. But after doing 
'export release build' the whole app is getting hanged whenever I try to download the image using the above code snippet.

Can anyone point me what could be the problem?

Comment: Are you using any ANE's at all?

Comment: Is it anything to do with ANE's? I am using LocalNotificationLib.ane and NetworkInfo.ane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug on adobe air. The issue is there for AIR 3.4. In adobe bug base this is tracked under Bug ID - 3320777 & Bug ID - 3519108. The only way to get around this problem is to load your first remote file a image file.

Answer (score 0):

It might be to do with ANE's. I just had a very similar experience where everything worked fine when publishing in debug mode, but when publishing for adHoc or distribution my app wouldn't load.

Although I am using Flash Pro this might help:

I resolved this by removing any references to the imported ANE's in the publish settings panel and saved my project. I then quit Flash Pro, relaunched it and loaded my fla file and checked that there still was no references to the ane's. I then added the references again and published my adHoc app successfully. Sounds quick and easy but it took me best part of a day to find that out!!!

Comment: I do not think it is related with ANE. In my case everything works working fine. Only when I am trying to download an image using the above piece of code the app freezes completely.

Comment: I would imagine then it has something to do with the URL of the image.

Comment: If the issue is with url then the issue should also be there in debug builds (like fast packaging, inside flex builder). But it is working fine in debug builds. The problem is only with release builds.